# Saving row number as a variable and referencing it in chart

Tags: vba, excel, function, reference

I'm creating a speadsheet where a user selects a cell on a row they want a chart to be generated, and Excel generates a chart in a range of cells in that row in another worksheet.

Before it generates the report, I save the row number as a variable so I can reference it later:

```
 activerow = ActiveCell.Row
```

I then want the chart title to reference a cell on the original spreadsheet.

```
 ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
 Dim activecharttitle As String
 activecharttitle = INDIRECT(activerow&"7")
 ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "='Sheet1'!activecharttitle"
```

I keep getting an error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone could please me out, that'd be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Adding more of my code:

```
    Dim activerow As String
        activerow = ActiveCell.Row
    Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 8), Cells(Selection.Row, 27)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'Sheet1'!$H$7:$AA$7")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
        "='Sheet1'!$H$6:$AA$6"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "='Sheet1'!$H$7:$AA$7"

    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    Dim activecharttitle As String
    activecharttitle = INDIRECT("B"&activerow)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "='Sheet1'!activecharttitle"
```

Comment: `INDIRECT(activerow&"7")` - what is this intended to do?  If `activerow` were (eg) 10, then this would evaluate to `INDIRECT(107)` Would probably be useful to post more of your code.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @TimWilliams. I was intending for INDIRECT to return the cell "B7" back to me. I've edited my post and added more of my code.

Comment: @Jessica see my code in my answer below, see if it works as you intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with `activecharttitle = INDIRECT(activerow&"7")` you are trying to get the text in Range of `activerow` and column "G", then you need to use `activecharttitle = Range("G" & activerow).Value2`.

I think you are after something like the code below:

```
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
Dim activecharttitle As String

activecharttitle = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & activerow).Value2
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "=" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & activerow).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Shai. You were correct and I mixed up the row/column values. I tried using the method you suggested but I got an error from the Range function.

Comment: I get a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed' error. The cell I want to reference is on a separate worksheet than the chart is on. I suspect that might the issue?